# meteor: Loop for blocks in template

Tags: javascript, meteor

My meteor-template has five times the same elemens. So I think it should be able to make a loop of it:

```
<table class="article" data-id="{{../article._id}}" data-section="something">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Something</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each something}}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{title}}" name="title"></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="article" data-id="{{../article._id}}" data-section="anything">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Anything</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each anything}}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{title}}" name="title"></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see the only difference is the data-element (something/anything), the th-element (Something/anything) and the each-element (something/anything). There are totally five tables like this. How do I make a loop of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one or two templates and two helper functions. I'll do it with two templates because it's clearer:

HTML:

```
<template name="outer">
  {{#each theFive}}
    <!-- ../article._id is referring to the data context of the parent of this template
    in reality you'll probably use ../this._id -->
    <table class="article" data-id="{{../article._id}}" data-section="{{someOuterThingKey}}">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{{someOuterThingKey2}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each something}}
          {{> inner}}
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="inner">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{title}}" name="title"></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.outer.helpers({
  theFive: function(){
    ...your code that builds the return variable
    return aCursorOrArrayWithTheFiveOuterThings;
  }
});

Template.inner.helpers({
  something: function(){
    ...your code that builds the return variable
    return aCursorOrArrayWithTheInnerThings;
  }
});
```